# Only a part of the TABLE should be transparent

Tags: css

I want the bottom of my table to be transparent and the top of it should be clear to read.

This is what I have tried:

```css
.preview {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%, rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0089fff1', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

This works fine and is exactly what I want. But there is a problem if you add content before that table, like:

```css
.preview {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%, rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0089fff1', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, et, cumque. Explicabo consectetur accusamus enim aspernatur veritatis facilis dolores ex necessitatibus beatae aliquam voluptatem debitis eaque neque, consequatur dolorem tenetur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita amet sequi, velit inventore aliquid in dicta ipsum fugiat recusandae iusto distinctio commodi est, asperiores neque hic consequuntur minima, sapiente numquam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nobis ex soluta eos deleniti, explicabo repellendus repellat rem aliquam quibusdam. Quo, qui, magni! Aperiam illum similique, id, dolor tenetur qui!
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

The problem may be because I am using `position: absolute` for the class `preview`. How should it be done correctly?

Comment: You need to wrap your table and the preview class with a `div` element and set it to `position: relative` so that the `preview` class will always be absolutely positioned relative to it

Comment: @Shahar that should not be a comment, since it's the best answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

I changed `top: 0` to `bottom:0` in `.preview`

Wrapped `table` and `<div class="preview"></div>` in a `div` with style `position:relative;`

```css
.preview {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%, rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 25%,rgba(255,255,255) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0089fff1', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, et, cumque. Explicabo consectetur accusamus enim aspernatur veritatis facilis dolores ex necessitatibus beatae aliquam voluptatem debitis eaque neque, consequatur dolorem tenetur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita amet sequi, velit inventore aliquid in dicta ipsum fugiat recusandae iusto distinctio commodi est, asperiores neque hic consequuntur minima, sapiente numquam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem nobis ex soluta eos deleniti, explicabo repellendus repellat rem aliquam quibusdam. Quo, qui, magni! Aperiam illum similique, id, dolor tenetur qui!
<div style="position:relative;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact an `absolute` element is always place relatively to the closest parent with `position: relative`

To achieve your issue you can use a `:before` pseudo element so you can remove the `preview` div

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

table.preview:before {
  content: "";
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0089fff1', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, et, cumque. Explicabo consectetur accusamus enim aspernatur veritatis facilis dolores ex necessitatibus beatae aliquam voluptatem debitis eaque neque, consequatur dolorem tenetur! Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita amet sequi, velit inventore aliquid in dicta ipsum fugiat recusandae iusto distinctio commodi est, asperiores neque hic consequuntur minima, sapiente numquam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipisicing elit. Quidem nobis ex soluta eos deleniti, explicabo repellendus repellat rem aliquam quibusdam. Quo, qui, magni! Aperiam illum similique, id, dolor tenetur qui!
<table class="preview">
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```